# Get first element in the list if the attribute is equal value - VUE.js

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom, css-selectors

I'm trying to add a class to the first div if the attribute is equal value.

What I have:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list__item" title="attr1">value 1</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr1">value 2</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 3</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 4</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 5</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 6</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 7</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

What I have:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list__item" title="attr1" class="active">value 1</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr1">value 2</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr1">value 3</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2" class="active">value 3</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 4</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 5</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 6</div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
const tags = ['attr1', 'attr2']

const collection = document.getElementByClassName("list__item")

// convert colelction into array
const arr = [...collection]

arr.forEach(el => {
    this.tags.forEach(tag => {
        if(tag == el.attributes.attr1.value) {
            document.querySelector(".list__item").classList.add('active')
        }
    })
})
```

What I'm getting is:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list__item" title="attr1" class="active">value 1</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr1">value 2</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr1">value 3</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 3</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 4</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 5</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 6</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that for the first iteration it's not adding the class to the first div with attr2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the tags. For each tag, you search for elements that have `title` equal to the tag. When you find the first one, you stop that specific tag and proceed to the next one.

Notice I use `for` in the inner loop, not `forEach`. This is because of the `return`, which stops the processing of the tag.

```js
const tags = ['attr1', 'attr2']

const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("list__item")

// convert colelction into array
const arr = [...collection]

tags.forEach(tag => {
  for(const el of arr) {
    if (tag === el.getAttribute('title')) {
      el.classList.add('active')
      return;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr1">value 1</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr1">value 2</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 3</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 4</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 5</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 6</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tags = ['attr1', 'attr2']

const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("list__item")

// convert colelction into array
const arr = [...collection]

//document.querySelector will always pick the first instance of a selector, even when 2 or more are present
//so for each tag, we can just find the first element with the title, and set that class

for( let tag of tags){

  let node = document.querySelector(`[title="${tag}"]`);
  node.classList.add("active");

}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="list__item" title="attr1">value 1</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr1">value 2</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 3</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 4</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 5</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 6</div>
    <div class="list__item"  title="attr2">value 7</div>
</div>
```